# Small mushroom in Massachusetts Identification?

Tags: united-states, massachusetts, fungi-identification, fungi

When researching for my field journal, I found this mushroom but I can't identify it. I was in Northeastern MA. [image: Mushrooms]

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that it is a [Lepiota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepiota), a genus of gilled mushrooms in the family Agaricaceae.

[image]

It could be an [Inocybe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inocybe), a genus of mushroom.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not an edible mushroom. I know this wasn't specially asked, but it is important non-the-less.